# Class object has no attribute

Tags: python, class, attributes

My code is shown down below. Whenever I try to test the `__str__` function it always gives me an

```
'Rectangle' object has no attribute 'h'.
```

This makes it seem as though I didn't define `h` in `__init__` but I did? I'm confused as to where I went wrong.

```python
class Rectangle:
    
      def __init__(self,x,y,w,h):
        if w<0 or h<0:
            raise ValueError 
        
        self.x= x
        self.y= y
        self.width= w
        self.height= h

      def height(self):
        return self.h

      def width(self):
        return self.w

      def x(self):
        return self.x

      def y(self):
        return self.y

   
      def __str__(self):
         return 'Rectangle(x= '+str(self.x)+', y= '+str(self.y)+',width= '+str(self.w)+', 
         height= ,'+str(self.h)+')'

r1= Rectangle (5,5,10,10)
r2= Rectangle (20,20,15,15)
```

Comment: `self.w` --> `self.width` and `self.h` --> `self.height` to match the variables assigned in `__init__()`.

Comment: Use `@properties` over `def height`

Comment: `This makes it seem as though I didn't define h in __init__ but I did?`: No, you didn't.

Answer (score 0):

> self.width= w

> self.height= h

should be

> self.w = w

> self.h = h

Comment: Thank you! I am no longer getting an error but I am getting ```<bound method Rectangle.__str__ of <__main__.Rectangle object at 0x10894f640>>```. Am I just inputting the test incorrectly? I was doing ```r1.__str__``` for example.

Comment: r1.__str__ is a function, you should be r1.__str__()